# Change icon "like" button class with Ajax form in ruby rails html view

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am struggling with getting my page to update an icon upon Ajax function success. The data is posted to the database successfully, but I still have to refresh the page for the content to update. I would like to change the icon (either by changing style or class) and display the new icon without the page refreshing.

This is my controller:

```
class VotesController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @vote = Vote.new
    @vote.voter_id = session[:user_id]
    @vote.post_id = params.fetch("post_id_from_query")
    @vote.bestoutfit_id = params.fetch("bestoutfit_id_from_query")

    if @vote.post_id == nil
      redirect_to("/feed", { :notice => "Vote failed to create successfully." })
    else
      @vote.save
      redirect_to({ :template => "/feed" })
    end
  end
end
```

My ajax function looks like this:

```
<script>

  $(function(){
  $(".post-form").on('click', function(event){
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: this.action,
      data: $(this).serialize(),
      success: function(response) {
        $('i').removeClass('far fa-heart').addClass('fas fa-heart');
      }
    });
    event.preventDefault();
  });
})

</script>
```

And my html code looks like this:

```
<form action="/insert_vote" method="post" class="post-form" data-remote="true">
<input type="hidden" value="<%= post.id %>" name="post_id_from_query">
<input type="hidden" value="<%= post.outfit1_id %>" name="bestoutfit_id_from_query">     
<button class="button"> 
<div class="arrow-left">
<p> <i class="far fa-heart"></i></p>
</div> 
</button>
</form>
```

I'm also getting this error:

```
VM268:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: Turbolinks is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:1
    at b (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Function.globalEval (jquery.min.js:2)
    at text script (jquery.min.js:2)
    at jquery.min.js:2
    at l (jquery.min.js:2)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:2)
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: instead of `i` you can use it's class selector. `$('.fa-heart').removeClass('far').addClass('fas');`

Answer (score 0):

In application.js, are you requiring jquery.turbolinks between jquery and turbolinks like below?

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require masonry/jquery.masonry
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree
```

If your turbolinks version is 5, jquery-turbolinks gem doesn't support turbolinks 5. So, at the moment, you have to add JS for compatibility referring to this [issue](https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks/issues/61) (see Lowryderch's comment). Put the turbolinks-compatibility.coffee under app/assets/javascripts/ folder

**if everything is correct.**

in your view

```
<span id="heart_div"> <i class="far fa-heart"></i></span>
```

in your JS Success function

```
$('#heart_div').html('<i class="fas fa-heart"></i>')
```

Comment: it actually ended up not being the main issue. Instead I rendered a partial view in the application controller. the turbolinks error seemed to be a problem with the way I had the Javascript file set up as well as the javascript call tag I had in the view file.